# `cannot move out of dereference of `&mut`-pointer` while building a sorted linked list

Tags: data-structures, rust

So, I'm learning Rust and decided to build a sorted linked list. Everything looks nice until I reach the add method, here's the code:

```
struct NodeItem<'a, V:'a + Ord> {
  value : V,
  next : Box<Option<NodeItem<'a,V>>> // '
}

impl <'a, V:'a + Ord> NodeItem<'a,V> { // '

  fn new(value : V) -> NodeItem<'a,V> { // '
    NodeItem { value : value, next : box None }
  }

  fn add(&mut self, value : V) {

    match self.value.cmp(&value) {
      Less => {
        self.next = box Some(NodeItem {value: self.value, next : self.next });
        self.value = value;
      },
      Equal | Greater => {
        match *self.next {
          Some(ref mut next) => next.add(value),
          None => self.next = box Some(NodeItem::new(value)),
        }
      },
    }

  }

}
```

The compiler complains with:

```
/home/mauricio/projects/rust/data_structures/src/lists/mod.rs:16:47: 16:51 error: cannot move out of dereference of `&mut`-pointer
/home/mauricio/projects/rust/data_structures/src/lists/mod.rs:16         self.next = box Some(NodeItem {value: self.value, next : self.next });
                                                                                                               ^~~~
/home/mauricio/projects/rust/data_structures/src/lists/mod.rs:16:66: 16:70 error: cannot move out of dereference of `&mut`-pointer
/home/mauricio/projects/rust/data_structures/src/lists/mod.rs:16         self.next = box Some(NodeItem {value: self.value, next : self.next });
```

What is exactly the problem here? I understand that I am moving a reference somewhere else, but shouldn't the lifetime parameters show that these items have a related "life"?

This is using the nightly from 21/12/14.

Comment: Creating a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help you understand the problem and also help us help you.

Comment: There are lots of questions about linked lists of this nature. Perusing some of those could prove useful as well. [Here's one from earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742032/boxed-value-does-not-live-long-enough) where Chris Morgan does a bang-up job explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [similar example](http://is.gd/tN9FSE):

```
enum E { Hello }
struct A(E);

fn main() {
    let mut a = A(E::Hello);
    let b = &mut a;
    let c = b.0;
}
```

And the errors:

```
<anon>:7:13: 7:14 error: cannot move out of dereference of `&mut`-pointer
<anon>:7     let c = b.0;
                     ^
<anon>:7:9: 7:10 note: attempting to move value to here
<anon>:7     let c = b.0;
                 ^
<anon>:7:9: 7:10 help: to prevent the move, use `ref c` or `ref mut c` to capture value by reference
<anon>:7     let c = b.0;
                 ^
```

Note that the compiler tells you how to prevent the error in this case.

The problem is that your `self.value` is not [`Copy`able](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/kinds/trait.Copy.html). That means that when you assign it, you are *moving* it out of the `NodeItem` (`self`), thus leaving it no longer fully defined! This would be a bad thing, so Rust prevents you from doing it.

You have to decide what the right way of fixing your problem is. The easiest is to ensure that `T` is copyable (or maybe [`Clone`able](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html), depending on your data). However, you probably *don't* want to be copying your data all around. I would investigate changing your code to prevent copying the node around and just updating entries. You may need to use something like [`swap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html).

#### Where I take all the fun out of exploring a new language

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    v: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn new(v: T) -> Node<T> { Node { v: v, next: None } }

    fn push_front(self, head: T) -> Node<T> {
        Node {
            v: head,
            next: Some(Box::new(self)),
        }
    }

    fn push_back(&mut self, tail: T) {
        match self.next {
            Some(ref mut next) => next.push_back(tail), 
            None => self.next = Some(Box::new(Node::new(tail))),
        }
    }

    fn push_after(&mut self, v: T) {
        let old_next = self.next.take();

        let new_next = Node {
            v: v,
            next: old_next,
        };

        self.next = Some(Box::new(new_next));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut n = Node::new(2u8);
    n.push_back(3u8);
    let mut n = n.push_front(0u8);
    n.push_after(1u8);

    println!("{:?}", n);
}
```

Comment: So, how do I represent a data structure when I need "add in the middle" semantics?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares there's multiple ways of solving your problem, as I alluded to in my last paragraph. You have to decide what is right for your solution.

Comment: I might be a little bit confused, but does Box::new(self) make a new copy of self?