# How to implement an addition method of linked list?

Tags: rust

I want to create a simple linked list and add a value into it. How should the `add` method be implemented to make this code output `100 50 10 5` at line 42, the second `root.print()` call?

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Node {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn print(&self) {
        let mut current = self;
        loop {
            println!("{}", current.value);
            match current.next {
                Some(ref next) => {
                    current = &**next;
                }
                None => break,
            }
        }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, node: Node) {
        let item = Some(Box::new(node));
        let mut current = self;
        loop {
            match current.next {
                None => current.next = item,
                _ => {} 
                //Some(next) => { current = next; }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let leaf = Node {
        value: 10,
        next: None,
    };
    let branch = Node {
        value: 50,
        next: Some(Box::new(leaf)),
    };
    let mut root = Node {
        value: 100,
        next: Some(Box::new(branch)),
    };
    root.print();

    let new_leaf = Node {
        value: 5,
        next: None,
    };
    root.add(new_leaf);
    root.print();
}
```

[(Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1b7c616277149ef01f5891e7e4e17da8&version=stable&backtrace=0)

I rewrote the function like this:

```
fn add(&mut self, node: Node) {
    let item = Some(Box::new(node));
    let mut current = self;
    loop {
        match current {
            &mut Node {
                     value: _,
                     next: None,
                 } => current.next = item,
            _ => {} 
            //Some(next) => { current = next; }
        }
    }
}
```

but the compiler says

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `item`
  --> <anon>:28:40
   |
28 |                 None => current.next = item,
   |                                        ^^^^ value moved here in previous iteration of loop
   |
   = note: move occurs because `item` has type `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<Node>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I don't understand why it says that item was previously moved if it's used only once, and how the `Some(_)` branch should be implemented to iterate through the list?

Comment: What makes you think that `kind` should be a reference (`&mut T`) instead of a plain value (`T`) ?

Comment: Because leaf becomes a branch after value is inserted. In code above leaf with `value` should be a branch after `newLeaf` added

Comment: @MatthieuM. I believe OP wants to specify that `kind` is mutable; but it is forbidden to simply write `kind: mut NodeKind`. The solution is to understand that mutability is inherited: nothing in the struct is `mut` *per se*, but a given instance *of the whole struct* is either `mut` or not. (I tried to find a good doc resource about that, but I couldn't find one?)

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: A reference is not necessary for this; I guess this is the source of your issue.

Comment: @mdup perhaps http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/mutability.html#field-level-mutability ?

Comment: @Shepmaster ok, I agree, see edit, I tried to explain as legibly as possible

Comment: @mdup: and then the next hurdle is that you cannot modify the content of a `Rc<T>`, you need either a `Box<T>` or `Rc<RefCell<T>>`

Comment: @Shepmaster perfect; for some reason it didn't show up while googling "rust mutability inheritance".

Comment: @mdup yeah, it doesn't say "inheritance" on that page :-)

Comment: @mdup: if you feel like putting together an explanation (I'm working on something else right now), please feel free to use: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=420bf067ca0ca572bdbc&version=stable (the compiling version); I moved to `Rc<RefCell<T>>` and moved print to recursive.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/27750985/155423 then? The answer explains how to create a singly-linked list.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I would be reluctant to call it a duplicate; I would be surprised if Alex was not more interested in understanding why rather than getting some linked-list code. Here, it appears the issue is (first and foremost) an issue of inherited mutability and lifetime. I also noted extraneous "mut" sprinkled in main, so maybe deep down a misunderstanding of what requires mutability and what does not. That moving does not require mutability can be surprising too, I guess.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yeah, that's why I just added it as a comment, not a close vote (which I can't do anymore, it turns out — yay gold badge!).

Comment: @MatthieuM. thanks for understanding, there is lack of info about Rust and those things, so only cut and try method is left and I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy: no worries, we're all in the same boat :)

Comment: Just a small nitpick: You *prepend*, *append* or *insert* into a list. Addition is usually a commutative and associative operation.

Comment: @llogiq append, of course. In most cases it's standard name for this method. `List.Add` in .Net or `ArrayList.Add` in Java, etc...

Comment: In the rust dictionary (see `std::collections::LinkedList`) it says you `push_back` an element but you can `append` one list to another..

Comment: @bluss thanks, it sounds like something new to me, but i'l consider it the next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you need to write it [(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ae2db7d9cf49a9c8f23ca241a10a149e&version=stable&mode=debug)

```
fn add(&mut self, node: Node) {
    let item = Some(Box::new(node));
    let mut current = self;
    loop {
        match moving(current).next {
            ref mut slot @ None => {
                *slot = item;
                return;
            }
            Some(ref mut next) => current = next,
        };
    }
}
```

Ok, so what is this?

**Step 1**, we need to `return` immediately after using the value `item`. Then the compiler correctly sees that it is only moved from once.

```
ref mut slot @ None => {
    *slot = item;
    return;
}
```

**Step 2**, to loop with a `&mut` pointer that we update along the way is tricky.

By default, Rust will **reborrow** a `&mut` that is dereferenced. It doesn't consume the reference, it just considers it borrowed, as long as the product of the borrow is still alive.

Obviously, this doesn't work very well here. We want a “hand off” from the old `current` to the new `current`. We can force the `&mut` pointer to obey
move semantics instead.

We need this (the `identity` function forces move!):

```
match moving(current).next
```

we can also write it like this:

```
let tmp = current;
match tmp.next
```

or this:

```
match {current}.next
```

**Step 3**, we have no current pointer after we looked up inside it, so adapt the code to that.

- Use `ref mut slot` to get a hold on the location of the next value.

Comment: Well, I've checked that `Some(ref mut next) => current = next` can be used as well. First step is clear too, but I can't understand the second step with braces. Why does they change behaviour so much?

Comment: Oh good point! I'll update the answer with more explanation I think

Comment: Thanks, I got the point with Identity function - afaik function always "consume" an argument if it isn't passed with `&` borrowed reference symbol, so it's clear, but I still don't understand why temp variable or code block works. I'm surprised that code block is valid because of lifetimes and all this stuff (it creates a temp variable that lives in this block only, but it's finishing right in the same moment as variable is created). Sorry if I'm annoying or my grammar is bad - I'm working hard on it :)

Comment: The temporary variable forces a move, that feels natural. *Why* the block works is not clear, it's natural to move there, but I think it could also reborrow. Not sure there is a *why*.