# Rewriting adding to a singly linked stack from a recursive implementation to iterative

Tags: rust

While learning Rust, I'm implementing a singly linked stack. I have the following structures defined:

```
type Link<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Link<T>,
}
```

I made the following function to push a value at the end of the stack:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn push_last(parent: &mut Link<T>, value: T) {
        match *parent {
            None => {
                *parent = Some(Box::new(Node { value: value, next: None }));
            },
            Some(ref mut boxed_node) => {
                Self::push_last(&mut boxed_node.next, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works great, so I'm happy with that. What I would like to do now is unroll the recursion into a loop. I tried to do it this way:

```
fn push_last(mut parent: &mut Link<T>, value: T) {
    loop {
        match *parent {
            None => {
                *parent = Some(Box::new(Node {
                    value: value,
                    next: None,
                }));
                break;
            }
            Some(ref mut boxed_node) => {
                parent = &mut boxed_node.next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty much the same, except parent is "incremented" in the function. However I get borrowing issues:

```
error: cannot assign to `*parent` because it is borrowed [--explain E0506]
   --> src/main.rs:15:21
    |>
15  |>                     *parent = Some(Box::new(Node {
    |>                     ^ assignment to borrowed `*parent` occurs here
...
21  |>                 Some(ref mut boxed_node) => {
    |>                      ------------------ borrow of `*parent` occurs here

error: cannot borrow `parent.0` as mutable more than once at a time [--explain E0499]
   --> src/main.rs:21:22
    |>
21  |>                 Some(ref mut boxed_node) => {
    |>                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |>                      |
    |>                      second mutable borrow occurs here
    |>                      first mutable borrow occurs here
...
26  |>     }
    |>     - first borrow ends here

error: cannot assign to `parent` because it is borrowed [--explain E0506]
  --> src/main.rs:22:21
   |>
21 |>                 Some(ref mut boxed_node) => {
   |>                      ------------------ borrow of `parent` occurs here
22 |>                     parent = &mut boxed_node.next;
   |>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `parent` occurs here
```

I really do not get why the first function works and not the second one since they are essentially the same.

Comment: Essential reading on this topic: ["Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists"](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/).

Comment: See also [How to implement an addition method of linked list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30441456/155423)

Comment: @JoeClay thanks, I was actually fiddling with the Stack implementation from the third chapter of the article

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks I found an answer there !