# match + RefCell = X does not live long enough

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I need to initialize an item (`fn init(&mut self) -> Option<&Error>`), and use it if there's no errors.

```
pub fn add(&mut self, mut m: Box<Item>) {
    if let None = m.init() {
        self.items.push(m);
    }
}
```

This works unless I need to check the error if there's any:

```
pub fn add(&mut self, mut m: Box<Item>) {
    if let Some(e) = m.init() {
        //process error
    } else {
        self.items.push(m); //won't compile, m is borrowed
    }
}
```

Fair. Need to use `RefCell`. However, this

```
pub fn add(&mut self, mut m: Box<Item>) {
    let rc = RefCell::new(m);

    if let Some(e) = rc.borrow_mut().init() {           
        //process error         
    } else {
        self.items.push(rc.borrow_mut())
    }
}
```

ends with weird

```
error: `rc` does not live long enough
        if let Some(e) = rc.borrow_mut().init() {
                     ^~
note: reference must be valid for the destruction scope surrounding block at 75:60...
    pub fn add_module(&mut self, mut m: Box<RuntimeModule>) {
                                                        ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 76:30
        let rc = RefCell::new(m);
```

I tried nearly everything: plain box, `Rc`'ed box, `RefCell`'ed box, `Rc`'ed `RefCell`. Tried to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742032/boxed-value-does-not-live-long-enough) to my case. No use.

Complete example:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::error::Error;

trait Item {
    fn init(&mut self) -> Option<&Error>;
}

struct ItemImpl {}

impl Item for ItemImpl {
    fn init(&mut self) -> Option<&Error> {
        None
    }
}

//===========================================

struct Storage {
    items: Vec<Box<Item>>,
}

impl Storage {
    fn new() -> Storage {
        Storage{
            items: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, mut m: Box<Item>) {
        let rc = RefCell::new(m);

        if let Some(e) = rc.borrow_mut().init() {           
            //process error         
        } else {
            self.items.push(*rc.borrow_mut())
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = Storage::new();
    let mut i = Box::new(ItemImpl{});
    s.add(i);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f738d6f5048c982aa0fbe049987fc094&version=nightly&backtrace=0))

UPD: As suggested, this is a "family" of mistakes like I did, it is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243606/if-let-borrow-conundrum). However my case has easier solution.

Comment: The `RefCell` will not resolve this issue. This is a know limitation of the borrow checker and there are some questions/answers about this. I pointed one possible duplicate, but I think we should find a definitive answer (if possible). @Shepmaster do you know a better duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If let borrow conundrum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243606/if-let-borrow-conundrum)

Comment: @malbarbo I don't think it's exactly the same as that one. It has to do with a returning a reference from a `&mut self` method. That causes the mutable borrow to persist. [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5a6c22cd3d19b5b5eb9f3a759ecb84aa)

Comment: Meanwhile I have found a solution, however it looks utterly ugly to me. https://gist.github.com/7f108112b95e2550691095e34c7cf37f

Comment: The simplest way would be to use early `return` after processing error.

@Shepmaster I think it's actually quite the same, `Option<Chars>` also borrows from `&mut self`, the lifetime parameter is just hidden by elision.

Answer (score 3):

As krdln suggested, the simplest way to work around this is to return in the `if` block and thus scope the borrow:

```
fn add(&mut self, mut m: Box<Item>) {
    if let Some(e) = m.init() {
        //process error
        return;
    } 
    self.items.push(m);
}
```

Comment: btw, this might be related https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/21906